# What does an empty iptables mean?

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I’m using CentOS and when type in the following [`iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) command:

```
iptables -L -v
```

The output is as follows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 19614 packets, 2312K bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target    prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13881 packets, 32M bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

What does this mean? I’m able to connect using SSH. Where can I see that rule?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Empty `iptables` rules simply mean you have no rules. Having no rules means the table “policy“ controls what happens to each packet traversing that table. The `policy ACCEPT` on each table means that all packets are allowed through each table. Thus, you have no firewall active.

Comment: @JakeGould Sure, that makes sense. Sill, `iptables` uses two distinct terms _rule_ and _policy_, and I was trying to stick to the tool's terminology.

Answer (score 4):

You don’t have any rules set up. Take a look at the [following `iptables` tutorial on how to add your rules](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/iptables-inbound-and-outbound-rules/).

You can add your SSH rule like so, which will allow all SSH through Port 22:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I was not clear. I'm surprising that how can I connect using SSH if I don't have any rule yet. What means empty table? Allow all connections or what?

Comment: @Memochipan Note how the listing contains the policy: "policy ACCEPT" -> that's the default rule, which in this case, is accept all traffic. Your iptables is effectively disabled as a firewall without any rules to block traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question when I wondered why iptables-save came up empty.
So although it's not an answer for the OP I thought I'd leave this here :)

It turns out that iptables-save needs the iptable_filter (and/or iptable_nat) modules loaded.

```
root@mgmt:~# iptables-save 
root@mgmt:~# modprobe iptable_filter
root@mgmt:~# iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Fri Aug  4 09:21:14 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:488]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:424]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug  4 09:21:14 2017
```

This matters when you try to a 'safe' test of some new rules:

```
iptables-save > /tmp/ipt.good; (sleep 60; iptables-restore < /tmp/ipt.good) & iptables-restore < iptables.rules.test
```